# Which way of writing functions is the most correct?

Tags: functions, notation, lambda-calculus

In functional programming it's not uncommon to bind a closure/lambda/anonymous function to a value name, i.e.
$$f = x \mapsto x^2 + 3$$

so I've been wondering which is more right to do in mathematics?

$$FToC(f) = (f - 32) * \frac{5}{9}$$
or
$$ FToC \colon f \mapsto (f - 32) * \frac{5}{9}$$

I mean in the end they both work the same way... it's $FToC(32) = 0$ in both cases

So is it just a matter of taste or is one actually more correct to use than the other?

Note that anonymous functions, or lambdas are sometimes also defined as so: $\lambda x.x+3$ which is effectively the same as $x \mapsto x+3$

For those not familiar, you can read more about lambdas [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)

Comment: Usually in math, the symbol $\mapsto$ is used rather than $\to$ in this context.

Comment: my bad, I wasn't aware of the difference, it's been changed now...

Comment: I've suggested to retag this; it has nothing to do with special functions.

Comment: thanks @Rhys I didn't see the "lambda calculus" tag anywhere, so I tagged it as a "special function" as in not a normal function...

Comment: Stackoverflow is probably a better place to ask a question about functional programming. Folks around here can tell you about the notations that mathematicians use to represent functions, but these are not necessarily appropriate in functional programming.

Comment: but this isn't a question about functional programming, it's a question about semantics in mathematics

Comment: @Electric Coffee: This is a normal function, in any reasonable mathematician's mind, since it's a garden-variety polynomial. There is no formal distinction in mathematics between named and anonymous functions; they're the same things, it's just you only named one of them. "Special functions" are interesting non-elementary (that's a technical term) functions like $\Gamma$.

Comment: @bubba: I think the question is "In functional programming, we do X. Is X or Y better in mathematics?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method A:

> $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $$f:x\mapsto (x-32)\cdots$$

Method B:

> $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $$f(x)=(x-32)\cdots$$

---

In my experience it is common in pure mathematics to use either of the above notations, though the latter is more compact and seen as slightly less formal though no less "correct" - A is usually only used to really emphasize important definitions, whilst B will usually be used in examples etc.

In applied mathematics, B is overwhelmingly the most common notation, though I'm sure all actual mathematicians would understand the former too, though they may raise eyebrows.

Note that the statement of the domain and codomain should be present in any formal definition, though it is omitted where it is obvious or familiar.

Note also that "pure" and "applied" mathematics are both complete fictions.

Comment: The two methods are also sometimes combined, as in things like $f(x) = y \mapsto y+x$ or similar.

Comment: That's a little misleading - that's an example of A and B being used for two **different** definitions of functions, not combined into one use. It's also an example of bad notation in my view! Comparatively rarely would I consider $f$ as an actual map from the reals into functions on the reals, for instance; so instead I would write $f_x:y\mapsto x+y$ or something. But yes, point taken!